# Jquery flowplayer - tabs - content inside div tags not displaying

Tags: jquery, flowplayer, jquery-tabs

I'm looking for a simple example of JQuery tabs in which I am planning to show two different forms.

I came across this example http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.htm which is perfect for my needs.

So I implemented the simple example. The code in question is:

```
<div class="panes"> 
    <div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div> 
    <div>Second tab content</div> 
    <div>Third tab content</div> 
</div>
```

Now my content for the first tab is a form which has several of its own div tags - when I put that form with div tags as the content for the first tab - nothing appears.

So I made a simple change and added another div tag to the content of the first tab as shown below and still nothing appears:

```
<div class="panes"> 
    <div><div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div></div> 
    <div>Second tab content</div> 
    <div>Third tab content</div> 
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to fix this. This is the content that I want to display in my first tab - Thanks for your help

```
<div id="formbox" class="formbox">    
<form id="shopping_form" method="post">

   <div id="3" style="width:520px;" >                      
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
   </div> 

   <div id="store_row" style="width:220px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Store</b>
       <input type="text" id="store" name="store" class="required" size="20" />
       <input type="hidden" id="store_id"/>                 
   </div>
   <div id="city_column" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>City</b>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="15"/>
   </div>                   
   <div id="findbutton_column" style="vertical-align:top;width:80px;float:left;">
    <input class="find_address" id="findaddress" type="button" value="Find Store"/>
   </div>

   <div id="googlerow" style="width:120px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;">
      <b>Select Store</b><select id="google_stores" name="google_stores"></select>
      <input type="hidden" id="google_address"/>                
   </div>

   <div id="google_message" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;"></div>
   <div id="locationrow" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;">
      <b>Address/Country</b>                 
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="20" />
      <input type="text" id="country" name="country" size="20"/>
   </div>

   <div style="width:520px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;" >
      <b>Price   
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="20" />    
   </div>    

   <div id="buttonrow" style="width:200px;float:right;display:none;" >  
      <input id="it" type="image" src="http://images.pe.com.s3.amazonaws.com/it.png" height="35px"/>            
   </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first example with NO additional divs, does it function correctly?

Comment: Yes that one works fine - if just add text it works - only if u add a div its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still partial to jquery ui tabs, but here is how to make it work with flowplayer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Tools standalone demo</title>
    <!-- include the Tools -->
    <script src="http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/combine/1.2.3/jquery.tools.min.js?select=full&debug=true"></script>
    <!-- standalone page styling (can be removed) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.flowplayer.org/tools/css/standalone.css"/>   
    <!-- tab styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.flowplayer.org/tools/css/tabs.css" />
    <!-- tab pane styling -->
    <style>
    div.wrap {
      width:700px;
      margin-bottom:40px;
    }
    .wrap .pane  {  
      background:#fff url(http://static.flowplayer.org/img/global/gradient/h150.png) repeat-x 0 20px;
      display:none;     
      padding:20px;
      border:1px solid #999;
      border-top:0;
      font-size:14px;    
      font-size:18px;
      color:#456;   

      _background-image:none;
    }
    .wrap .pane p {
      font-size:38px;   
      margin:-10px 0 -20px 0;   
      text-align:center;
      color:#578;
    }
    .clearfix:after {content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
    .clearfix {display:block;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- the tabs -->
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- tab "panes" -->
    <div class="pane clearfix">
      <div id="formbox" class="formbox">    
      <form id="shopping_form" method="post">
         <div id="3" style="width:520px;" >                      
              <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
         </div> 
         <div id="store_row" style="width:220px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Store</b>
             <input type="text" id="store" name="store" class="required" size="20" />
             <input type="hidden" id="store_id"/>                 
         </div>
         <div id="city_column" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>City</b>
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="15"/>
         </div>                   
         <div id="findbutton_column" style="vertical-align:top;width:80px;float:left;">
          <input class="find_address" id="findaddress" type="button" value="Find Store"/>
         </div>
         <div id="googlerow" style="width:120px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;">
            <b>Select Store</b><select id="google_stores" name="google_stores"></select>
            <input type="hidden" id="google_address"/>                
         </div>
         <div id="google_message" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;"></div>
         <div id="locationrow" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;">
            <b>Address/Country</b>                 
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="20" />
            <input type="text" id="country" name="country" size="20"/>
         </div>
         <div style="width:520px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;" >
            <b>Price   
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="20" />    
         </div>    
         <div id="buttonrow" style="width:200px;float:right;display:none;" >  
            <input id="it" type="image" src="http://images.pe.com.s3.amazonaws.com/it.png" height="35px"/>            
         </div>
      </form>
      </div>    
    </div> 
    <div class="pane">
      <p>#2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <p>#3 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This JavaScript snippet activates those tabs -->
  <script>
  // perform JavaScript after the document is scriptable.
  $(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane");
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will note that this works perfectly in FF, but you may need to tweak the css for Safari and chrome to get tabs 2 and 3 working right.
Didn't test with IE.

Look at how flowplayer does the multiple nested tabs.  Instead of the second set of tabs you would have your form.  Just remember you will need that clearfix class to wrap up your form.  Here is flowplayers example: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/multiple-tabs.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
  .clearfix:after {content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
  .clearfix {display:block;}
  </style>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
    </script>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab (Form)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1" class="clearfix">
        <div>
          <div id="formbox" class="formbox">    
          <form id="shopping_form" method="post">
             <div id="3" style="width:520px;" >                      
                  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
             </div> 
             <div id="store_row" style="width:220px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Store</b>
                 <input type="text" id="store" name="store" class="required" size="20" />
                 <input type="hidden" id="store_id"/>                 
             </div>
             <div id="city_column" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>City</b>
              <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="15"/>
             </div>                   
             <div id="findbutton_column" style="vertical-align:top;width:80px;float:left;">
              <input class="find_address" id="findaddress" type="button" value="Find Store"/>
             </div>
             <div id="googlerow" style="width:120px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;">
                <b>Select Store</b><select id="google_stores" name="google_stores"></select>
                <input type="hidden" id="google_address"/>                
             </div>
             <div id="google_message" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;"></div>
             <div id="locationrow" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;display:none;">
                <b>Address/Country</b>                 
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="20" />
                <input type="text" id="country" name="country" size="20"/>
             </div>
             <div style="width:520px;float:left;padding-bottom:10px;" >
                <b>Price   
                <input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="20" />    
             </div>    
             <div id="buttonrow" style="width:200px;float:right;display:none;" >  
                <input id="it" type="image" src="http://images.pe.com.s3.amazonaws.com/it.png" height="35px"/>            
             </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Second Tab Content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Third Tab Content</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I have looked at this example as well - this is from the Jquery official website right - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#source - Yeah this one does work but I was trying to figure out how to make the flowplayer one work