# jQuery Tabs - Content not showing after adding new tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have a simple asp.net web page that worked correctly until I added a forth jQuery tab.  No matter what content I put on the 4th tab, nothing on it gets rendered.

After searching through a about dozen SO posts I thought I found a solution here: [Jquery flowplayer - tabs - content inside div tags not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066539/jquery-flowplayer-tabs-content-inside-div-tags-not-displaying) ...  but still can't get it to work.

I'm new to jQuery, JavaScript and asp so be gentle :)

Thanks in advance for your time.

```
 <div class="tabWrapper">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Current Status</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Budget vs. Actual</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Projected Expense</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>Expense History</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNoDataFound" runat="server">No data available at this time.</asp:Panel>
                <asp:GridView ID="expenditureSummaryGrid" class="multiRowCashTable" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>    <%--close tab 1--%>
            <div id="tabs-2" >
                <div class="buttonContainer"><button class="balanceButton" onclick="toggleButton('balance'); return false;" title="Help">Hide Balance Table</button></div>
                <asp:GridView ID="balanceGrid" class="multiRowCashTable" runat="server"></asp:GridView>  
                <div class="buttonContainer"><button class="expenseButton" onclick="toggleButton('expense'); return false;" title="Help">Show Expense Table</button></div>
                <asp:GridView ID="expenseGrid" class="multiRowCashTable" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                <div class="buttonContainer"><button class="budgetButton" onclick="toggleButton('budget'); return false;" title="Help">Show Budget Table</button></div>
                <asp:GridView ID="budgetGrid" class="multiRowCashTable" runat="server"></asp:GridView> 
            </div>    <%--Close Tab 2--%>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <asp:Panel ID="divProjectionHeader" runat="server">                
                    <table class="tblProjectHeader">
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:label ID="Label1" class="makeBold" runat="server" >Current Award Year: </asp:label><asp:label id="lblCurrAwardYear" runat="server" ></asp:label></td>
                            <td><asp:label ID="Label2" class="makeBold" runat="server" >Months Remaining: </asp:label><asp:label id="lblRemainingMonths" runat="server" ></asp:label></td>
                            <td><asp:label ID="Label3" class="makeBold" runat="server" >Burn Rate Months: </asp:label>
                                <asp:DropDownList id="selBurnRateMonths"
                                    AutoPostBack="True"
                                    EnableViewState="True"
                                    runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>                        
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td><asp:label ID="Label4" class="makeBold" runat="server" >Months Included:</asp:label><asp:label id="lblBurnRateMonths" runat="server" ></asp:label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                                     
                </asp:Panel>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlProjection" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="divCalc" runat="server">
                    <button id="calcButton" onclick="calcAdjustedBalance(); return false;"  >Calc</button>
                    <button id="zeroButton" onclick="calcZero(); return false;"  >Zero</button>
                    <button id="resetButton" onclick="resetForm(); return false;"  >Reset</button>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>    <%--Close tab 3--%>
            <div id="tabs-4" >
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>    <%--Close tab 4--%>
        </div>    <%--Close tabs--%>        
    </div>  <%--Close Tab Wrapper--%>
```

Init logic:

```
    // On Doc Ready
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Config Tabs
        $(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });  // End Config Tabs
```

Not sure if this helps but, I noticed strange indexing behavior prior to adding the forth tab.  I use a select to dynamically change the initial tab that opens:

```
    If IsPostBack Then

        Dim SenderName As String
        SenderName = clsWebUtil.GetPostBackControl(Me)

        If SenderName = "selBurnRateMonths" Then
            hfSelectedTab.Value = 3
        Else
            hfSelectedTab.Value = 0
        End If

    End If
```

The strange part is, the index has to be "3" to access the third tab.  Since they are zero-based, I thought it should be index "2".  Perhaps the embedded divs on "tabs-2" causes the issue?

Comment: Can you show us how you initialize your tabs in jQuery?

Comment: Additional code follows this snippet:   
        // On Doc Ready
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Config Tabs
            $(function () {
                $('#tabs').tabs();
            });  // End Config Tabs

Comment: Code looks okay at a glance.  This may sound silly, but are you building before you refresh the browser?

Comment: I have saved the page and rebuilt the solution.  I am using "View in Browser" within Visual Studio 2010 to check the page.

Comment: Looks fine. Does the javascript console give you any error?

Comment: I'm using Chrome's debugger and do not see any errors there.  However, it does show tab-4 nested in tab-3.  But I don't see a coding error to cause that :(

Comment: When I view source, I see the markup for tab-4.  It is not visible on the screen though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After playing around with it for hours, it turned out nested `div` and jQuery `Accordion`s were messing up the the last tab somehow. I ended up moving the markup for my last tab **to the top of first tab**. In your case, it'd be something like

```
<div id="tabs-4" >
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">
   <br />
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlNoDataFound" runat="server">No data available at this time.</asp:Panel>
   <asp:GridView ID="expenditureSummaryGrid" class="multiRowCashTable" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Note that at runtime the tabs will show in the same order as your list:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Current Status</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Budget vs. Actual</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Projected Expense</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>Expense History</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So moving the markup won't change the ordering.